Is it okay to pray to God to destory hell?
It is a win-win situation if Hell is destroyed. So what about praying to God to destory Hell so that all Mankind will enter paradise. So is it wrong to pray to God to remove the Hell and judgement and pray to God to give highest paradise for all human kind?

That would be unrighteous, to suggest that the Judge of all the earth should dispense with all judgment.

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help, below, as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice.

It's a win-win if hell is destroyed? I see how that might be considered a win for those condemned, but who's the other winning party?

if you compare earth with universe, it is simply nothing. so god will consider our activities as nothing, may be if we prayed and will give all of us paradise?

Human beings are not nothing in God's design. While we are very small in size, we are the only thing that God made in his image. And God thought that we are important enough that he became one of us and died as one of us in order to save us from our sins.

Remember what Jesus prayed - "Thy will be done". Who put hell there in the first place, allows it to stay there, and made sure to tell us about it? If I pray asking God to destroy hell, isn't that suggesting that I know better than He does how to run His kingdom?

How is it "win" if incorrigible unrepentant sinners, who don't even want God's salvation, are given eternal life along with those that are saved? Do you want to live in the "mansion" between Hitler and Hannibal Lecter?

In addition to the 17000 pagers of Q&A that Nigel mentioned, please see the note on the side bar.  Asking something like this is probably something someone should talk to a pastor about.  If you had a particular faith tradition you could ask about - this question could be answered objectively.  But since you don't have that in the question it's hard to answer concretely.  Universalists might already believe this, I believe some Christians believe Hell may be destroyed at the end of time and others aren't so sure.

You would benefit from taking the Christianity Stack Exchange Tour in order to find out what sort of questions are acceptable - and what sort of questions will be closed: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Welcome to the website, from an eastern orthodox perspective what you are asking for would require the elimination of free will. Hell is for us the same as heaven, it is all about your perspective. Think of a very bright magnesium fire. If you stare into it definitely you will suffer and burn, if you look at everything it illuminates for you then it is a pure light that allows you to see everything clearly. (It is a very rough analogy, but this is a comment).

Truthfully, I thought something very similar the other day. "Is it okay to hate Satan?" I'm talking about absolute wrathful hate. In my mind, the answer is probably, "No" because we are supposed to live the way Jesus wants us to and to have that much rage about Satan is sinful.

It may be helpful, at the outset, to clearly define what you mean by "hell" and whether that squares with the Bible's eternally burning sulphuric lake of fire that Satan and his hordes (including those unrepentant sinners who have him as their 'father') are finally cast into (Revelation 20:10-15).
After all, that same passage says:

"And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and death and hell
delivered up the dead which were in them, and death and hell were cast
into the lake of fire. And they were judged every man according to
their works. And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This
is the second death. And whosoever was mot found written in the book
of life was cast into the lake of fire." KJV

This means that once all the dead are resurrected and judged, with those unfit for God's holy presence being cast into that lake of fire where Satan and his hordes already are, then the emptied grave (hell) and the now-powerless death are the final things to go into that eternally burning lake of fire.
God himself has told us what he is finally going to do with the emptied hell. But he has also told us that some who are resurrected from the grave (hell) will never get into his holy presence. Heaven is his domain, his abode. He decides who gains entry into his holy presence. The call to holiness is throughout the entire Bible. Woe betide those who ignore that call, thinking that, at the end of the day, God will sweep their unrepented-of-sin under some spiritual carpet, and nod them through into paradise with a nod and a wink. Oh, how sinful humanity loves the idea of a "win-win" situation. Anything, just so long as they can continue in their chosen path of treating God as benignly sympathetic to them, no matter how little regard they pay to God's perfect righteousness and justice. I hope the OP is far removed from such near-contemptuous thinking about the Creator, who knows the difference between the righteous and the wicked (Genesis 18:23).
